# How to keep empty items when iterating over a list containing empty elements with `with_items`

Tags: ansible

I am running ansible 2.4. Given the following playbook, how do I test for empty elements in `list.msg`? It seems that Ansible does not loop over the empty items in my list.

```
---
- name: Check for empty items
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    "list": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": [
            [
                "foo"
            ],
            [
                "bar"
            ],
            []
        ]
    }

  tasks:
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item | length }}"
      failed_when: item | length == 0
      with_items: "{{ list.msg }}"
```

I get the following result:

```
PLAY [Check for empty items] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=foo) => {
    "msg": "3"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=bar) => {
    "msg": "3"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ansible > 2.5, you can get the desired behaviour by using [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops) rather than `with_items`. In your case (ansible < 2.5) you should be able (did not test directly) to achieve the same result by using [`with_list`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-list) instead of `loop` (although you should definitely consider upgrading)

Using `with_items` is actually calling the [corresponding lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/items.html). Quoting the doc:

> this lookup returns a list of items given to it, if any of the top level items is also a list it will [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#list-filters) it, but it will not recurse

`flatten` is what is causing the empty element to evaporate in your case. This is a desired behavior so you can easily loop over several list at once like in the following example:

```
with_items:
  - [a, b]
  - [c, d]
```

resulting in a single list `[a, b, c, d]` being looped over.

Changing your current task to

```
    - name: test
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item | length }}"
      loop: "{{ list.msg }}"
      failed_when: item | length == 0
```

gives the following result (ansible 2.8.4):

```
TASK [test] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['foo']) => {
    "msg": "1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=['bar']) => {
    "msg": "1"
}
failed: [localhost] (item=[]) => {
    "msg": "0"
}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "All items completed"}
```

As you can see, the empty list is now part of the iterated items instead of being skipped because of applying the `flatten` filter. Meanwhile, you are now iterating other a list of lists rather than a list of strings as before as you can notice in the `length` result being `1` *element* (and not `3` *letters*). You'll have to take this into account for your future tasks.

Vladimir's answer gives some more good practice you could benefit from although the real problem here is using `loop` with raw data rather than filtered with `with_items`.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: "How do I test for empty elements in list.msg?"

A: It is possible to test the length of the list and skip empty lists in the loop instead of letting the play fail. For example the task below

```
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item|length }}"
  loop: "{{ list.msg }}"
  when: item|length > 0
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'foo']) => 
  msg: '1'
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'bar']) => 
  msg: '1'
skipping: [localhost] => (item=[])
```

Comment: Thanks, but can this be done in Ansible 2.4? I dont get skipping

Comment: Ansible 2.4 does not have the `loop` keyword, it was introduced in ansible 2.5. `with_items` will filter out your empty list before it is even looped over, see my answer. Ansible 2.4 is quite old, you should consider upgrading.

Comment: @Dejan I Just edited my answer to add a potential solution for ansible 2.4.